# Is this valid syntax for defining methods in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been defining methods this way in my Vue app:

```
methods: {
  myMethod(arg) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

This is the way you typically see it:

```
methods: {
  myMethod: function (arg) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

My way looks a little cleaner, and both ways to work fine, but am I committing a great JS sin here? Will this come back to bite me somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's just a short way to define a method in ECMAScript 2015

[Method definitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)